# Codebook in C++

Tags: c++, encryption

Trying to create a codebook in C++ for little kids. Just a letter switching algorithm, where they provide an input and I put it in and its encrypted or decrypted accordingly.

Here is the code that I have written so far but the replace function changes all of the string every single time instead of only once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string message, decision;
int number;
cout << "Hello! What is your message?" << endl;
cin >> message;
cout << "\n";
cout << "How are you changing your message? (e/d)" << endl;
cin >> decision;
cout << "\n";
cout << "Which way will you do that?" << endl;
cin >> number;

if(decision == "e"){
    if(number == 1){
        cout << "e_one" << endl;
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'a', 'n' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'b', 'o' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'c', 'p' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'd', 'q' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'e', 'r' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'f', 's' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'g', 't' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'h', 'u' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'i', 'v' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'j', 'w' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'k', 'x' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'l', 'y' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'm', 'z' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'n', 'a' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'o', 'b' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'p', 'c' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'q', 'd' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'r', 'e' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 's', 'f' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 't', 'g' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'u', 'h' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'v', 'i' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'w', 'j' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'x', 'k' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'y', 'l' );
        replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'z', 'm' );
        cout << message << endl;
    }
  if(number == 2){
        cout << "e_two" << endl;
    }
    if(number == 3){
        cout << "e_three" << endl;
    }
    if(number == 4){
        cout << "e_four" << endl;
    }
    if(number == 5){
        cout << "e_five" << endl;
    }
}

if(decision == "d"){
    if(number == 1){
        cout << "d_one" << endl;
    }
    if(number == 2){
        cout << "d_two" << endl;
    }
    if(number == 3){
        cout << "d_three" << endl;
    }
    if(number == 4){
        cout << "d_four" << endl;
    }
    if(number == 5){
        cout << "d_five" << endl;
    }
}
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

If I input the following string 
`input = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`
I get the following output after running it through the algorithm: 
`output = 'abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm'`
And this is what I am hoping to get as the output but for watever reason I can't figure out how to do it. 
`expected output = 'nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm'`

Please let me know how I can fix this in order to make it work like I would like it to.

Comment: Of course - your `replace` calls aren't aware of the `replace` calls that have gone before. Wouldn't you be better off looping over the string and transforming each character individually, in turn?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could you give me an example of what you mean? Its been a while since I worked in C++.

Comment: Honestly I'd rather you gave it a go first - that was a pretty big clue!

Comment: If you're having trouble decoding LRiO's clue, it's worth [looking at the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

Comment: Not related to your question, but you probably could replace the 26 calls to `replace` by a loop and a table( roughly 5 times less lines)

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Not related? Pretty sure that's the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

We’ll ignore style and complexity for a moment and focus just on your problem. You have this code:

```
// …
replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'a', 'n' );
// … lots of other stuff …
replace( message.begin(), message.end(), 'n', 'a' );
// …
```

… hopefully that makes the problem clear.

Comment: If you mean algorithmic complexity then it's O(n) either way, of course..

Comment: When I went back through the code, I realized that that is my issue and I need to fix it. I was hoping I could get some direction on other avenues of tackling this problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, it's O(n), but there is a noticable difference between n and 26*n.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, should have been clearer: I meant code complexity.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Okay

Comment: @petersohn: Not disputing that there is a substantial difference in actual runtime